# How to use git in system with no fork(2)?

Tags: windows, git, mingw

Is it possible to properly use git when working fork(2) is not available? If so, how?

MinGW environment dies not provide fork(2) implementation. Some git sub-processes (chiefly fetch-pack) rely on it, and will fail if it does.

Is it possible to go around that without patching out its usage? Maybe telling server to disable its side-band capabilities?

Comment: I wonder what real problem you're trying to solve as [the official Git port to Windows](http://git-for-windows.github.io) had long ago solved it.

Comment: I would like to know how. As far as i am able to tell, they make do with msys which does have fork(2) implemented

Comment: Well, I think we may be talking past each other ;-) My question was like «GfW already provides almost 100% complete Git _natively_ working on Windows, so what _real problem_ are you trying to solve—as it appears to be a non-issue (for GfW)?» Don't forget that your question is tagged `git`, not `mingw` or `msys`. To rephrase: you install GfW, and it works—plain and simple. Why would you care how it implements `fork(2)` or works around its absense thereof, if any?

Comment: There is no 'real problem', i suppose. What i want to do is to build and fruitfully run git on mingw and learn some things in process. I have tagged the question with "mingw" as well, now

All in all, it bothers me that git for windows may not have properly working mingw implementation - why, in that case, it has provisions in its configuration and code for mingw?

Comment: BTW see [this](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/fork(),-exec(),-CreateProcess():-Windows-vs-Linux) from the [GfW's wiki](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/).

Comment: I am reassured to see my statement (about lack of fork(2) in MinGW) told from authorative source. A piy the wiki does not go into details about how things are implemented

Comment: Please never hesitate to include [direct links to the authoritative sources you use](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/git-for-windows/IAb3tnn3lpU/o0Gb7ExwAQAJ) so that they can be studied and verified, if needed ;-)

Comment: Eh, my own question in mailing list does not count as an authorative source. the answer does, though

Comment: yes, that's what I meant—as you referred to that particular answer, I reckoned.